# Add column with number of block per group with tidyverse

Tags: r, group-by, tidyverse

I have a dataframe like this:

```
tibble(group = c(rep("A", 10),
                 rep("B", 10),
                 rep("C", 10)),
       disease_presence = c(rep("yes", 2), rep("no", 15),
                            rep("yes", 1), rep("no", 2),
                            rep("yes", 3), rep("no", 2), rep("yes", 1), rep("no", 2), rep("yes", 2)))
```

I want to add a column that gives me the block number of consecutive "yes" per group, like this:

```
tibble(group = c(rep("A", 10),
                 rep("B", 10),
                 rep("C", 10)),
       disease_presence = c(rep("yes", 2), rep("no", 15),
                            rep("yes", 1), rep("no", 2),
                            rep("yes", 3), rep("no", 2), rep("yes", 1), rep("no", 2), rep("yes", 2)),
       disease_ID = c(1,1, rep(NA, 15), 1, rep(NA, 2), 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, 3, 3))


#------------


# A tibble: 30 x 3
   group disease_presence disease_ID
   <chr> <chr>                 <dbl>
 1 A     yes                       1
 2 A     yes                       1
 3 A     no                       NA
 4 A     no                       NA
 5 A     no                       NA
 6 A     no                       NA
 7 A     no                       NA
 8 A     no                       NA
 9 A     no                       NA
10 A     no                       NA
11 B     no                       NA
12 B     no                       NA
13 B     no                       NA
14 B     no                       NA
15 B     no                       NA
16 B     no                       NA
17 B     no                       NA
18 B     yes                       1
19 B     no                       NA
20 B     no                       NA
21 C     yes                       1
22 C     yes                       1
23 C     yes                       1
24 C     no                       NA
25 C     no                       NA
26 C     yes                       2
27 C     no                       NA
28 C     no                       NA
29 C     yes                       3
30 C     yes                       3
```

I would like the solution to be within the tidyverse pipe syntax. I tried different combinations of `case_when`, `cum_sum`, `lag` and `lead` but was not able to solve it so far. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a custom function with `rle` -

```
apply_func <- function(x) {
  x <- with(rle(x == 'yes'), rep(cumsum(values) * values, lengths))  
  x[x == 0] <- NA
  x
}
```

and apply it by group.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(disease_ID = apply_func(disease_presence)) %>%
  ungroup

#   group disease_presence disease_ID
#1      A              yes          1
#2      A              yes          1
#3      A               no         NA
#4      A               no         NA
#5      A               no         NA
#6      A               no         NA
#7      A               no         NA
#8      A               no         NA
#9      A               no         NA
#10     A               no         NA
#11     B               no         NA
#12     B               no         NA
#13     B               no         NA
#14     B               no         NA
#15     B               no         NA
#16     B               no         NA
#17     B               no         NA
#18     B              yes          1
#19     B               no         NA
#20     B               no         NA
#21     C              yes          1
#22     C              yes          1
#23     C              yes          1
#24     C               no         NA
#25     C               no         NA
#26     C              yes          2
#27     C               no         NA
#28     C               no         NA
#29     C              yes          3
#30     C              yes          3
```

Answer (score 0):

Great answer by @Ronak

I would do the same:

```r
assign_IDs <- function(x) {
  with(rle(x), rep(cumsum(values) * values, lengths)) %>% 
    replace(. == 0, NA_integer_)
}
df %>%
  mutate(disease = disease_presence == "yes") %>%
  select(-disease_presence) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(disease_ID = assign_IDs(disease)) %>%
  ungroup()
```